# How to simplify code for translation of more then 5000 characters

Tags: string, list, split, google-translation-api

I am relatively new to programing and I am creating a tkinter program that translates text through several languages at once and I have a problem I am trying to translate large amount of text (more than 5000 which is the limit of google translate api) so in other to do that I try to split the text into multiple parts:

```
txt_str = "some text"
split_strings = []

n  = 3000
for index in range(0, len(txt_str), n):
     separated_strings = txt_str[index : index + n]

     split_strings.append(separated_strings)
```

Howewer this only creates a list and separate the string by commas which is great but since I am afraid that separation only by commas might not work I need to iterate over a list of lists so that my translations stay intact.

I found the function that is able to do that:

```
def makelists(split_strings):
    lst = []
    for fr in split_strings:
        sep = fr.split(', ')
        lst.append(sep)      
    return(lst)

ortexter = makelists(split_strings)
```

Then I translate the lists and to save the text I append the values to a new list:

```
tom=[]
languages=["ko","cs","en"]

for whole_text in ortexter:
        for lng in languages:
            the_translate_text = translator.translate(bž,lang_tgt=lng)
            bž = the_translate_text
            time.sleep(1)
            print("translate was successful")
            tom.append(bž)
```

Then I convert the list of translated lists to string and remove the Breckets leftovers:

```
def listToString(s): 
    str1 = "" 
    for ele in s: 
        str1 += ele
    return str1 

tom = listToString(tom)
x = tom.replace("[", "")
x = x.replace("]","")
```

I am glad that it works but is there a way how to simplify it.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Could you provide overview what you want to simplify it? Cloud translation API as stated in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas): `The Cloud Translation API is optimized for translating smaller requests. The recommended maximum length for each request is 5K characters`. But as you are using large amount of text its not better to use [Document Translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-documents)? You can use `Docx` or `PDF` and daily limit is 2,6k pages daily. Or you want to simplify your code?

Comment: Well I think the metod that I am using for spliting the text and then creating the list for splited parts is just too complicated as well as the metod that i am using to put the text back together I personally think that it could be simplified like from text to list of lists and from list of translated text imediatelly back. i thought of finding api that that could support larger guantities of characters but since i am still new to python I dont want to spend money on it since it is just a project for fun and my personal learning.

Comment: The whole thing that I am using to achieve is just my idea with the help of the internet(for spliting the text and creating lists for splited parts) if there is a way is simplier free way of translating larger amounts of text throught the translation api(because i am new to learning i am using free version) without the need of spending money I am up for it.

Comment: The app has a few windows for the text input text output and a language input and after presinig a button the text gets translated throught all inputed languages and at the end puts the translated version of the input to text output window